# discord.js bloquear mensagem de comando em canais específicos

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de que os usuarios podessem colocar comandos em lugares especificos(na sala de commandos) como eu posso fazer isso, pois como eu tentei está dando erro

```
client.on('message', message =>{

    const prefix = config.prefix

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.channel.cache.get() == client.channels.cache.get('787113881197740103')||message.channel.cache.get() == client.channels.cache.get('787060910605991966')){
        message.reply("Vai no canal certo vagabundo!")
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente fazer desta maneira:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const prefix = config.prefix
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.id != 'id do canal de comandos') {
        return message.reply('**Vai no canal certo!**')
    }
}
```